# Encounter crystal report errors with vb net while running the application

Tags: python, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am developing PoS system for a shop using VB.net 2015 and SQL server 2014.
I faced a lot issues to find out the right version of Crystal Report for my project but fortunately i find it.
I created `*.rpt` file using Crystal Report and add Crystal Report viewer to a Form (everything was good).
But when I run my project I encounter 18 errors (as shown in an Image).

Crystal Report Errors:

```
[![Crystal Report Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1yug.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1yug.png)
```

Button Code:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If (ds.Tables.Contains("user")) Then
            ds.Tables.Remove("user")
        End If
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from TabUser"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = cn
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "user")
        Dim cr As New CrystalReport1
        cr.SetDataSource(ds.Tables("user"))
        Form1.CRviewver.ReportSource = cr
        Form1.CRviewver.Refresh()
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Looks to me like you’re missing the required references.  Check the references for the project in the solution panel, look for anything with a yellow explanation mark beside it and replace/update as required